# Remove headerbox background color

Tags: backgrounds, posters, baposter

How do I remove the headerbox background color to match the poster background?.

In this code, the last `\headerbox` background is white, I want it to match the poster background:

```
\documentclass[a0paper,portrait]{baposter}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %unicode support
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\selectcolormodel{cmyk}
\begin{document}

\definecolor{darkgreen}{cmyk}{0.8,0,0.8,0.45}
\definecolor{lightgreen}{cmyk}{0.8,0,0.8,0.25}

\begin{poster}
{
grid=false,
headerborder=open, % Adds a border around the header of content boxes
colspacing=1em, % Column spacing
bgColorOne=white, % Background color for the gradient on the left side of the poster
bgColorTwo=lightgray, % Background color for the gradient on the right side of the poster
borderColor=darkgreen, % Border color
headerColorOne=green, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (left side)
headerColorTwo=green, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (right side)
headerFontColor=white, % Text color for the header text in the content boxes
boxColorOne=white, % Background color of the content boxes
textborder=rounded, %rectangle, % Format of the border around content boxes, can be: none, bars, coils, triangles, rectangle, rounded, roundedsmall, roundedright or faded
eyecatcher=false, % Set to false for ignoring the left logo in the title and move the title left
headerheight=0.11\textheight, % Height of the header
headershape=rounded, % Specify the rounded corner in the content box headers, can be: rectangle, small-rounded, roundedright, roundedleft or rounded
headershade=plain,
headerfont=\Large\textsf, % Large, bold and sans serif font in the headers of content boxes
%textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}}, % Uncomment for paragraph indentation
linewidth=2pt % Width of the border lines around content boxes
        }
{}
%
%
{\vspace{0.4em}
\huge{\textsf %Sans Serif
{TITLE}
}}


\headerbox{1. Introduction}{name=introduction,column=0,row=0, span=3}{}

\headerbox{2. Background}{name=model,column=0,below=introduction,span=1}{}

\headerbox{}{name=foottext, headershape = rectangle, column=0, span=3, above=bottom, textborder=none,headerborder=none,boxheaderheight=0pt}{ SOME TEXT\\ WHERE\\ BACKGROUND SHOULD\\ MATCH WITH POSTER.
}

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

When I use `boxColorOne=none`, I recieve an error.

Comment: Interesting. It gives an error when I compile your code as well. Perhaps you can provide a more comprehensive, *minimal* document rather than the current code snippet. It'll allow us to better figure out what's going on. Can you do that?

Comment: To elaborate on what @Werner said (welcome to TeX.SE by the way!) is that it is currently difficult to provide an answer to your question because it does not contain enough information. At the very least we need to know the document class for your poster. The easiest way to provide sufficient information is by making a small _complete_ document, which can be compiled by just copyign the code without adding anything, and that demonstrates the issue. Make it short, so include only relevant things while making sure that the remaining code can still be compiled.

Comment: Use `background=none` or `background=plain` in poster options.

Comment: @ferahfeza I don't want the background to be plain. I want to have the background inside the `headerbox` to match the background of the poster. In other words the background of the `headerbox` should be transparent completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE.

The default background is set in the class (`baposter.cls`) to `shadeLR` (`background=shadeLR`). This setting takes two colors: `bgColorOne` (white), on the left, which blends into `bgColorTwo` (lightgray) on the right.

To apply the same settings to the `posterbox` we just need to replicate the settings that apply when we have `background=shadeLR` in settings for the `posterbox`.

So, to that particular poster box environment, we add:

```
boxshade=shadelr,boxColorOne=white,boxColorTwo=lightgray
```

There is a remnant of the `boxheader` when we have `headershape=rounded` set as a key in the `poster` environment. This can be fixed either by adding `headershape=rectangle` to override the environment setting (`headershape=rounded`), or remove the rounded corners with `cornerradius=0em`.

Note also that `headerbox` is a macro and was deprecated. Its replacement is the `posterbox` environment, which I used here. A key difference is that the `posterbox` environment can accept code that uses the `verbatim` environment.

`baposter.cls` already sets the colour model to `CMYK` and compilation with `pdflatex` defaults to `utf8`, so `\selectcolormodel{cmyk}` and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` are redundant here.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a0paper,portrait]{baposter}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %unicode support
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%\selectcolormodel{cmyk}
\begin{document}

\definecolor{darkgreen}{cmyk}{0.8,0,0.8,0.45}
\definecolor{lightgreen}{cmyk}{0.8,0,0.8,0.25}

\begin{poster}
{
grid=false,
headerborder=open, % Adds a border around the header of content boxes
colspacing=1em, % Column spacing
bgColorOne=white, % Background color for the gradient on the left side of the poster
bgColorTwo=lightgray, % Background color for the gradient on the right side of the poster
borderColor=darkgreen, % Border color
headerColorOne=green, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (left side)
headerColorTwo=green, % Background color for the header in the content boxes (right side)
headerFontColor=white, % Text color for the header text in the content boxes
boxColorOne=white, % Background color of the content boxes
textborder=rounded, %rectangle, % Format of the border around content boxes, can be: none, bars, coils, triangles, rectangle, rounded, roundedsmall, roundedright or faded
eyecatcher=false, % Set to false for ignoring the left logo in the title and move the title left
headerheight=0.11\textheight, % Height of the header
headershape=rounded, % Specify the rounded corner in the content box headers, can be: rectangle, small-rounded, roundedright, roundedleft or rounded
headershade=plain,
headerfont=\Large\textsf, % Large, bold and sans serif font in the headers of content boxes
%textfont={\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}}, % Uncomment for paragraph indentation
linewidth=2pt % Width of the border lines around content boxes
        }
{}
%
%
{\vspace{0.4em}
\huge{\textsf %Sans Serif
{TITLE}
}}

\headerbox{1. Introduction}{name=introduction,column=0,row=0, span=3}{}

\headerbox{2. Background}{name=model,column=0,below=introduction,span=1}{}

%\headerbox{}{name=foottext, headershape = rectangle, column=0, span=3, above=bottom, 
%textborder=none,headerborder=none,boxheaderheight=0pt}
%{ SOME TEXT\\ WHERE\\ BACKGROUND SHOULD\\ MATCH WITH POSTER.
%}
\begin{posterbox}[name=foottext, column=0, span=3,above=bottom, textborder=none,boxheaderheight=0pt,
                  headerborder=none,boxshade=shadeLR,boxColorOne=white,boxColorTwo=lightgray,cornerradius=0em]
                  {} % empty header=boxheaderheight=0pt, cornerradius=0em OR headershape=rectangle
                  SOME TEXT\\ WHERE\\ BACKGROUND SHOULD\\ MATCH WITH POSTER.
\end{posterbox}

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```